# actuator port in >= Spring Boot 2.3.4

Tags: spring-boot, port, spring-boot-actuator

Is it still possible to change the actuator port in 2.3.4?
neither `management.port` nor `management.endpoints.port` seems to work. Intellij doesn't recognize any of these settings, either.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want the actuator to be available on a different port than the web root of an application, say I've got localhost:8080/hello that prints hello  and localhost:8081/actuator/health that shows the health of the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `management.server.port`. [Customizing the Management Server Port](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port)

With these settings:

```
server:
  port: 8082

management:
  server:
    port: 8081
```

the default app port is 8082 and the actuator data is exposed at 8081